# How to move cursor in TextInput while app running in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

So basically I'm creating a date TextInput box, when you enter the first 2 digits the TextInput box will automatically add the colon `:`

For example when you type in the TextInput 2 digits `11` it will add the `:` and turn it to `11:`

and when you continue to type in the next 2 digits `22` it will continue to add the `:` and turn it to `11:22:`

But the problem is the cursor stop right before the colon like this:

[image]

So I wonder if there is any way to make the cursor move after the colon right after it added the colon like this?

[image]

I tried to search for all the same questions in StackOverFlow but they all seem to be a bit outdated, complex, and not working for me. I tried the `instance.cursor = (len(instance.text), 0)` to move the cursor to the end but seems like I need to declare another method to refresh my TextInput but I can't find out how.

```
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.core.window import Window

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string("""
<KTextInput>:
    hint_text: "00:00:00"
    
""")

class KTextInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(text=self._on_text)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        self.t = text
                    
    def _on_text(self,instance,text):
        "This is to check when to add colon"
        if (len(text)==2 and text[1] != ":") or (len(text)==5 and text[4] != ":"):
            self.text+=":"
        
        "This is to check if the input is digits or not, if not they will be not type in"
        try:
            if not self.t.isdigit() and self.t != ":":
                self.text=self.text.replace(self.t,"")
        except Exception:
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from kivy.app import App
    class TestApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return KTextInput()
    
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cursor_movement()` method of `TextInput`, but you must delay it slightly to allow your changes to the `text` to take effect. Like this:

```
def _on_text(self, instance, text):
    "This is to check when to add colon"
    if (len(text) == 2 and text[1] != ":") or (len(text) == 5 and text[4] != ":"):
        self.text += ":"
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.do_cursor_movement, 'cursor_end'))
```